# jquery get selected option in SELECT

Tags: jquery

Is there any difference between

```
$("#myselectname option:selected").val()
```

and

```
$("#myselectname").val()
```

, where myselectname is identifier for a SELECT. I can see both return the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the first gets the value of the selected option, the second gets the value of the select itself, and the select will have a value equal to the selected option, so they will both return the same value, but they are not the same thing.

The last one is usually the best option, as it has a selector that only uses getElementById, and no DOM traversal, and as such will be faster and more direct.

Comment: +million if i Could give..!

Comment: Is there any scenario where this two can be used for different purpose (i mean unlike this case, both can't be used to serve purpose)? Thanks

Comment: and ofcourse, which one is the preferable method if I just want to get the value of selected option? First one?

Comment: I think you're mistaken here. The functionality of the two is absolutely identical.

Comment: @AbdullahFahim - Sometimes you'll need the selected option, say for instance if you need a data attribute or something, and then that selector is useful. For getting the value, just targeting the select will do.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt it is most certainly not identical. and not only is it not identical, it's very simple. the first one returns the value of whatever is actually selected by the user, whereas the second one just returns whatever value is currently in the select element. in a scenario that grabs the value after a user has made a selection this would make no difference, but if let's say, you wanted to grab the value of whatever is in the select box upon the page loading, the first option would return you nothing while the second option would give you what you want.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - You're right, they do the exact same thing, in that they both get the same value, but they are still different as they target different elements in the DOM.

Comment: "but they are still different as they target different elements in the DOM." exactly

Comment: thanks .. that means if I need only value of selected option, I should use second method, e.g. $("#myselectname").val()?

Comment: and in all fairness, OP asked if there were ANY differences between these two uses. so we simply told him what the difference was

Comment: @iAmClownShoe in the case of `val()`, they're identical. He wasn't asking if `$("#myselectname option:selected")` and `$("#myselectname")` were the same, he was asking if calling `val()` on both of them is identical.

Comment: @AbdullahFahim - Yes, a selector using just an ID is always preferable over DOM traversal and more complex selectors.

Comment: @iAmClownShoe the only difference between those two lines of code is that they look different. Functionally, they are 100% identical. And in response to your use case with the page load, you're wrong there too. Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLcFM/)

Comment: @iAmClownShoe and check out this [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/). Do a ctrl + F for "selects and checkboxes"

Comment: As for functionality, they are not the same. The difference is'nt in val(), it's in the selector, and the selector targets two completely different DOM elements, even if the returned result is the same.

Comment: why is that so hard to understand? what adeneo and i are saying is the same thing. we are agreeing that it gives the same value but it's what your grabbing the value from that is slightly different. u mad bro?

Comment: @adeneo hence the functionality is the same, lol. They both have the same function. Their function, in this case, is to return the selected value of a select list. You're thinking of **procedurally**.

Comment: @iAmClownShoe I would never get mad on stack :) I do, however, have a hard time dropping something when I'm right.

Comment: @adeneo How do you think that `$(checkbox).val()` gets its value? I'll give you a hint. It involves `option:selected`.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - seriously, it does **not** involve `option:selected`, it's a native functionality of HTML/JS, so there's no need for jQuery to do something other than invoke `select.value` -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YSN8t/)

Comment: @adeneo Now we're getting somewhere. And how do you think the value property works?

Comment: @adeneo What I'm getting at is that no matter which way you look at it, the two different methods get the value the same way -- by parsing through the children of the select for an `option` that is selected. Unless the value gets set on change or something, but that would be a pretty big duplication of logic.

Comment: The value of the select is automatically set to the same value as the first selected option by the browser, that's in the [**specs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement), but that's not the issue, targeting two completely different DOM elements does not constitute doing the same thing even if they both return the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. No difference whatsoever. `val()` returns the currently selected item. The only difference there is that the second version is marginally faster since the first version is redundant.

Comment: this is wrong... adeneo's answer is correct. there is a difference it is just not noticeable in this scenario but there are potential cases where it would be different.

Comment: @iAmClownShoe Can you perhaps name a few of those cases?

Comment: @iAmClownShoe .. Yaa, I am also interested to know whether any such case exists or not?

Comment: @Phillip Schmidt ... little confused now ... from adeneo's reply, it seems like first one should be faster ...

Comment: @AbdullahFahim The second one is definitely faster, but by such a little margin that it could never be an issue. And in response to your other question, they're both wrong. It's the same.